# Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome 3 WM suspend graphical problem

Tags: gnome, drivers, graphics, window-manager

So when I suspend my computer, the screen when my computer is locked or when I have opened the menu with windows button suddendly becomes bugged and looks like an old kinescope TV with no signal.
Is this somesort of a driver problem? I am using a amd latest 64 bit linux proprietary driver.
Or is it Gnome 3 problem for which I should just wait for a fix?

Comment: What graphics card to you have?

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 5650 using the latest beta drivers.

Comment: Sure it's about grahpics card tough?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it always helps to know.